# InvocationTargetException with RollingFileAppender in Log4J2

Tags: log4j2

I'm trying to use a RollingFileAppender in Log4J2 and apparently I'm missing something.  The file is created with 0 bytes, but no logging goes to it.  When I turn on the trace I see the following error message logged (to the console) by log4J2:

```
2014-07-08 19:51:11,354 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager c:/logs/blah.log
2014-07-08 19:51:11,464 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.108079890 seconds
2014-07-08 19:51:11,465 ERROR Unable to invoke method createAppender in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.createPluginObject(BaseConfiguration.java:913)
```

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="TRACE" verbose="false">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="Blah" fileName="c:/logs/blah.log" filePattern="c:/logs/blah-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c: %m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="Blah" level="INFO"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

It's probably something basic but I can't find it.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create a ticket on the Log4j2 issue tracker so the team can take a look at it? It may be a bug in version rc2. (I'm assuming you are using rc2 and have both the api and core jars in the classpath.)

---

Thanks!
I took a look and the class at the beginning of the stack trace (`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration`) no longer exists in log4j-core-2.0-rc2. It was renamed to `AbstractConfiguration`.

So I think this error is caused by an old log4j-core-2.0-rc1 jar that is still floating around somewhere.

Comment: Done.  I was on rc1 but have now upgraded to rc2 and I still see the same issue.  The problem goes away when I switch to a FileAppender.